# XCode: UIWebView Mail Links Not Working?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, hyperlink, mailto

I have a webpage which I am navigating UIWebView to and that page has images and links which use the "mailto:" tag. Unfortunately, when you tap on them, nothing happens. If you hold the links, there is an option to email them though.

How can I fix this issue? I've searched around and couldn't find anything on it.

Comment: Is it on device or on simulator? There is no mail app on simulator and mailto link doesn't work on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myWebView.dataDetectorTypes=UIDataDetectorTypeAddress;
```